# Jsoup, extract links, images, from website. Exception on runtime

Tags: java, jsoup

I am just starting to play around with Jsoup, so followed the tutorial they had on there website. This code i assume should work fine but when i am running it on netbeans I am coming across errors.

This is the code i am using:

`

```
/**
 *
 * @author Slabs One
 */
public class ParseWebpage {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "http://www.gumtree.com.au/");
    String url = args[0];
    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
    Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

    print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
    for (Element src : media) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
            print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                    src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                    trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
        else
            print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
    }

    print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
    for (Element link : imports) {
        print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
    }

    print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
    }


}

 private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}

private static String trim(String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width)
        return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
    else
        return s;
}

}
```

`

There shouldnt be any problems with this code, but on runtime i get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.gumtree.com.au/
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
at parsewebpage.ParseWebpage.main(ParseWebpage.java:25)
```

Any insight to why this is not working would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, it looks like you aren't running it with any command line arguments, and that `Validate` is making sure you're running it with one command line argument.

Comment: Sorry for some reason the full class wasnt coppied over.

I have

`package parsewebpage;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;`

      
At the top of the class, not sure why that didnt get coppied over on the initial post

Comment: I am following [link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

Comment: You need to pass an URL as an argument to your program.

Comment: The code checks that the method was called with an argument, are you sure that you are providing a runtime argument?  I am more familiar with eclipse than netbeans, but with eclipse you can right click in the class, choose 'run as', then 'run configurations...'.  One of the tabs lets you specify runtime arguments.  I'm sorry I don't know how to do that in netbeans, but hopefully I have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To pass *command line arguments* in `Netbeans`, You have to do the following.

- Right-click the project and click properties
- Choose *Run* in the side pane
- Choose your Main class (ParseWebpage) using *Browse* dialog
- Input the Arguments (URL)
- Click ok

Now, if you run the Main class (ParseWebpage), the run time argument will be passed in NetBeans IDE